# How to automatically translate a taxonomy term upon insertion in D7?

Tags: drupal-7, translation, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I have a 'lot' of taxonomy terms to import (from german) and I want to translate them into french and english.

I have a nice php snippet to translate using google translate api; which works fine.

I'm using feeds import and feeds tamper to do my hierarchy but i can only insert in the current site language.

From drupal api; on D7 i found the following hook :

```
function hook_taxonomy_term_insert($term) {
  if (!empty($term->synonyms)) {
    foreach (explode("\n", str_replace("\r", '', $term->synonyms)) as $synonym) {
      if ($synonym) {
        db_insert('taxonomy_term_synonym')
        ->fields(array(
          'tid' => $term->tid, 
          'name' => rtrim($synonym),
        ))
        ->execute();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But i'm not sure how to add a 'create a translated term' in here.

I'm sure it's pretty easy but can't figure out where to put this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as just creating the term and inserting the language. Depending on whether you're using localize or translate the way of persisting the translations is different too...